# DNS record for staging site

Tags: domain-name-system, a-record

I want to set up a dns record for our staging site which is on a different server.  Say if our domain is www.example.com can I simply create a new `A` record for www.staging.example.com pointing to a different IP address?

Comment: +1 for asking instead of groping around for a subdomain solution for a trivial problem

Comment: @BrandonXavier, I'm not used to working with DNS records and just wanted to ask someone to be 100% sure

Comment: I agree totally and don't mind a bit - my comment above was in response to a downvote (which in my opinion was unwarranted) and not worded very well to reflect that it was directed at the downvoter not you. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

```
www.staging     IN A  your.staging.ip.address
```